# Does SMLNJ have any sort of debugger?

Tags: smlnj

I have looked through the [SMLNJ User Guide](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/index.html) and can't find anything about debugging capabilities. I'd love to just see a stack trace, or step through a function. Is this possible. Are there other implementations for similar variants of SML that *do* provide this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From section 3.3 of the [SMLNJ faq](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/faq.txt):

> Q: Is there a debugger for SML/NJ? 
>   What ever happened to Tolmach's
>   debugger for SML/NJ 0.93?
>
> A: The short answer is no.

[Also:](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=html&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2F209.85.229.132%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AxG1EiMSjqmsJ%3Awww.cs.berkeley.edu%2F~aiken%2Fcs294_F01%2Flectures%2Flecture04.ppt%2Bsml%2Bdebugger%26cd%3D3%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Duk&ei=dlbqSbPrN6OUjAeayoybCg&usg=AFQjCNFRgvpxXqo8NE2ps4pnGRHR9M8gTg&sig2=nDwHr46SOFcecGJGFeT-5A)

> ```
> Debugging SML 
>
>     * For years, no one had an SML debugger
>
>     * Why?
>           o No one had any bugs?
>           o It is hard to write a debugger for SML
>           o The user community wasn’t large enough
>
>     * Likely all three are true
> ```

There's [a .NET compiler](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/tsg/SMLNET/), though, which claims to have some debugging support..

Comment: Your "Also" Berkeley link is dead (unsurprisingly - it seems to have referenced some kind of Google cache of a website accessed by a direct IP instead of a domain name)

Answer (score 13):

There's currently no step-based debugger.

You can get stack backtraces by doing the following:

```
- CM.make "$smlnj-tdp/back-trace.cm";
[library $smlnj-tdp/back-trace.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj-tdp/plugins.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-LIB/Util/smlnj-lib.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/compiler/current.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/compiler/x86.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/core.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/parser.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/basics.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/elaborate.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/elabdata.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/MLRISC/MLRISC.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-MLRISC/MLRISC.cm is stable]
[library $Lib.cm(=$SMLNJ-MLRISC)/Lib.cm is stable]
[library $Control.cm(=$SMLNJ-MLRISC)/Control.cm is stable]
[library $Graphs.cm(=$SMLNJ-MLRISC)/Graphs.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/MLRISC/Control.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/debugprof.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/execute.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/internal/smlnj-version.cm is stable]
[library $smlnj/viscomp/x86.cm is stable]
[New bindings added.]
val it = true : bool
- SMLofNJ.Internals.TDP.mode := true;
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val it = () : unit
-
```

Then, you can load some code and instead of just printing the exception, you'll get a simulated stack backtrace. You do have to recompile your code after following the above steps, or this won't work!

```
- exception Foo;
exception Foo
- fun otherFun() = raise Foo;
val otherFun = fn : unit -> 'a
- fun raiseAtZero(n) = if (n > 0) then raiseAtZero(n-1) else otherFun();
val raiseAtZero = fn : int -> 'a
- raiseAtZero 10;
stdIn:9.1-9.15 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
   value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)

*** BACK-TRACE ***
GOTO   stdIn:7.5-7.27: otherFun[2]
          (from: stdIn:8.60-8.70: raiseAtZero[2])
CALL-( stdIn:8.5-8.70: raiseAtZero[2]
          (from: stdIn:9.1-9.15: it)
GOTO   stdIn:5.5-5.27: otherFun[2]
          (from: stdIn:6.60-6.70: raiseAtZero[2])
CALL-( stdIn:6.5-6.70: raiseAtZero[2]
          (from: stdIn:6.71-6.86: it)

uncaught exception Foo
  raised at: stdIn:7.24-7.27
-
```

Answer (score 9):

There is now a source level debugger in PolyML: http://www.polyml.org/documentation/Tutorials/Debugging.html

Answer (score 4):

[Poly/ML](http://www.polyml.org) is the best unknown implementation of Standard ML.  It had a command-line debugger from early on (at least the 1990s). Recently, it has acquired full IDE support via Isabelle/PIDE, e.g. see [ML](http://sketis.net/category/ml), which also includes a source-level debugger.