# exit, abort, sleep for debugging?

Tags: sleep, sml, trace, smlnj, abort

In Prolog you can activate trace mode for debugging. Apparently there is no such thing in ML. Is there at least a `exit()` or `abort()`? A `sleep()` would also be useful to approximate trace mode from Prolog, when combined with debug print statements.

Comment: Maybe not exactly a duplicate, but this question seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/764362/4996248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force an exit, you can use the `OS.Process` structure:

```
 OS.Process.exit OS.Process.success;
```

Also note that Poly/ML does have a good [debugger](http://www.polyml.org/documentation/Tutorials/Debugging.html).